# recvmsg returned EDEADLK?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, linux-kernel

I have socket family PF_PACKET type SOCK_RAW. Messages read via recvmsg and with poll(). Rendomly and periodicly I got recvmsg return EDEADLK. I try debug this problem with next code. I try investigate who and how blocked my socket descriptor. May be some one know other method how debug such case? As I right understand

EDEADLK resource deadlock avoided. An attempt was made to lock a system resource that would have resulted in a deadlock situation. In my case it is socket file descriptor locking problem. Allocating a system resource socket file descriptor would have resulted in a deadlock situation. The system does not guarantee that it will notice all such situations. This error means you got lucky and the system noticed.

```
error = recvmsg(fd, &msghdr, flags);
msghdr_flags = msg_hdr.msg_flags;

void recvmsg_errno(int fd, unsigned int msghdr_flags, int flags, int error)
{
    struct flock fl;
    memset(&fl, 0x0, sizeof(fl));

    printf("recvmsg return: %d errno: %d description: %s\n", error, errno,
                    strerror(errno));

    printf("recvmsg flags: %x %d\n", flags, flags);
    if (flags & MSG_ERRQUEUE) printf("MSG_ERRQUEUE\n");
    if (flags & MSG_OOB) printf("MSG_OOB\n");
    if (flags & MSG_PEEK) printf("MSG_PEEK\n");
    if (flags & MSG_TRUNC) printf("MSG_TRUNC\n");
    if (flags & MSG_WAITALL) printf("MSG_WAITALL\n");

    printf("msghdr flags: %x %d\n", msghdr_flags, msghdr_flags);
    if (msghdr_flags & MSG_EOR) printf("MSG_EOR\n");           //indicates end-of-record; SOCK_SEQPACKET
    if (msghdr_flags & MSG_TRUNC) printf("MSG_TRUNC\n");       //discarded datagram was larger than the buffer supplied
    if (msghdr_flags & MSG_CTRUNC) printf("MSG_CTRUNC\n");     //control data were discarded due to lack of space in the buffer
    if (msghdr_flags & MSG_OOB) printf("MSG_OOB\n");           //out-of-band data were received
    if (msghdr_flags & MSG_ERRQUEUE) printf("MSG_ERRQUEUE\n"); //no data received; extended error from the socket error queue

    flags = 0;
    flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETLK, &fl); {
            printf("F_GETLK: 0x%x\n", flags);
            printf("l_start: %x l_len: %x l_pid: %d l_type: %x l_whence: %x\n",
                            fl.l_start,   //Starting offset for lock
                            fl.l_len,     //Number of bytes to lock
                            fl.l_pid,     //PID of process blocking our lock (F_GETLK only)
                            fl.l_type,    //Type of lock: F_RDLCK, F_WRLCK, F_UNLCK
                            fl.l_whence); // How to interpret l_start: SEEK_SET, SEEK_CUR, SEEK_END
    }//Get the first lock which blocks the lock description

    flags = 0;
    flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFD); {
            printf("F_GETFD: 0x%x\n", flags);
    }//Get the file descriptor flags

    flags = 0;
    flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL); {
            printf("F_GETFL: 0x%x\n", flags);
            if (flags & O_NONBLOCK) printf("O_NONBLOCK\n");
            if (!(flags & O_NONBLOCK)) printf("BLOCK\n");
            if (flags & O_APPEND) printf("O_APPEND\n");
    }//Get the file status flags and file access modes

    flags = 0;
    flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETOWN); {
            printf("F_GETOWN: %d\n", flags);
    }//Socket, set the process or process group ID specified to receive SIGURG signals when out-of-band data is available.
}
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's the `recvmsg()` that's returning `EDEADLK`? I've only seen `EDEADLK` in conjunction with file locks and threads (also did a `man -K EDEADLK` and couldn't find anything else), neither of which is directly related to sockets.

Comment: Please show how you're calling `recvmsg_errno()` in relation to the `recvmsg()` call, chances are `errno` is being clobbered by other calls, or set by a prior call in the case recvmsg() didn't actually fail.

Comment: My previous scenario: error = recvmsg() and I got error = 35; I found EDEADLK     35  /* Resource deadlock would occur */. And now I try catch that error with additional debug code recvmsg_errno();

Comment: @cosinus0: You should be checking if `error == -1`. If it is, then `errno` will have the error number. Was that what you meant? `recvmsg()` returns the size of the received message, or -1 on errors.

Comment: Sorry bad explanation. if ((error = recvmsg()) <= 0) {return -errno;} and I got returned value -35 (errno == 35).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If [`recvmsg()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmsg.2.html) returns 0, it does not mean an error occurred. It means that the other end closed the connection.

In a followup comment to the question, the OP mentioned that they used *`if ((error = recvmsg()) <= 0) {return -errno;}`*. This is wrong. When the other end closes the connection, `recvmsg()` returns zero, without setting `errno`. Even the use of variable named `error` is wrong, as the function returns the number of bytes received.

In other words, the OP is seeing an old, stale `errno == EDEADLK` from some other earlier failed locking function, and handling the case where the other end closes the connection incorrectly as an error.

(`errno` is only set when an error occurs; no library function clears it to zero, ever, because that could cause errors to be hidden in certain cases.)

Comment: Also returns 0 if the iov_len of the attached iovec is set to 0.